# Pivot without aggregating

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot, ssms

I have such a table, where I would like to transpose the value column to Timestamp and Value. Unfortunately with Pivot I have to use an agregate function on value, so I obtain just one row.

any Idea?

| Area | Sensor | Type | value | key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | termometer | Temperature | 2022-01-01T00:00:01.0030000Z | t |
| 1 | termometer | Temperature | 24 | v |
| 1 | termometer | Temperature | 2022-01-01T00:00:02.8760000Z | t |
| 1 | termometer | Temperature | 25 | v |
| 1 | termometer | Temperature | 2022-01-01T00:00:04.8760000Z | t |
| 1 | termometer | Temperature | 25 | v |
| 1 | termometer | Temperature | 2022-01-01T00:00:06.9300000Z | t |
| 1 | termometer | Temperature | 35 | v |
| 1 | termometer | Temperature | 2022-01-01T00:00:09.0410000Z | t |
| 1 | termometer | Temperature | 36 | v |
| 1 | termometer | Temperature | 2022-01-01T00:00:11.1310000Z | t |
| 1 | termometer | Temperature | 37 | v |
| 1 | termometer | Temperature | 2022-01-01T00:00:12.9160000Z | t |
| 1 | termometer | Temperature | 32 | v |
| 1 | termometer | Temperature | 2022-01-01T00:00:14.9490000Z | t |
| 1 | termometer | Temperature | 30 | v |
| 1 | termometer | Temperature | 2022-01-01T00:00:17.3900000Z | t |
| 1 | termometer | Temperature | 24 | v |
| 1 | termometer | Temperature | 2022-01-01T00:00:19.3410000Z | t |
| 1 | termometer | Temperature | 27 | v |

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without PIVOT. Since you don't have primary key in table if you set row order by Sensor you would get desired output.

```
with cte_main (sensor,val,rn,[key],Area,[Type]) as (
    SELECT SENSOR,[VALUE],
    ROW_NUMBER()over(order by sensor),[key] RN
    ,Area,[Type]
    FROM sf_question
)

SELECT cte_main.Area,
       cte_main.[Type],
       cte_main.Sensor, cte_main.val, child.val 
FROM cte_main 
LEFT JOIN cte_main child on cte_main.rn = child.rn + 1
where cte_main.rn % 2 = 0
```

Output:

| Area | Type | Sensor | t | v |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Temperature | termometer | 24 | 2022-01-01T00:00:01.0030000Z |
| 1 | Temperature | termometer | 25 | 2022-01-01T00:00:02.8760000Z |
| 1 | Temperature | termometer | 25 | 2022-01-01T00:00:04.8760000Z |
| 1 | Temperature | termometer | 35 | 2022-01-01T00:00:06.9300000Z |
| 1 | Temperature | termometer | 36 | 2022-01-01T00:00:09.0410000Z |
| 1 | Temperature | termometer | 37 | 2022-01-01T00:00:11.1310000Z |
| 1 | Temperature | termometer | 32 | 2022-01-01T00:00:12.9160000Z |
| 1 | Temperature | termometer | 30 | 2022-01-01T00:00:14.9490000Z |
| 1 | Temperature | termometer | 24 | 2022-01-01T00:00:17.3900000Z |
| 1 | Temperature | termometer | 27 | 2022-01-01T00:00:19.3410000Z |

Comment: i was thinking along the same lines but with (order by sensor ROWS BETWEEN current row and 1 following), but i don't see how we can say the order of the rows is correct nothing to order on and nothing linking the time and the measurement

Comment: @ufosnowcat Yes, the main problem is he doesn't have any connection between rows. No order by , this is really bad practice doing here.